# How do I use multiple data locations with Priam?

Tags: java, priam

I want the Netflix Priam to use the directories `/priam/first/data`, `/priam/second/data`, and `/priam/third/data`. This is issue because the Cassandra database is configured to store its data in multiple locations.

In the file *Priam.properties* I've tried setting the property `priam.data.location` to `\n- /priam/first/data\n- /priam/second/data\n- /priam/third/data`, but I am getting this in the error log:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The configured 'data file location' does not exist: 
- /priam/first/data
- /priam/second/data
- /priam/third/data
```

so it seems that Priam reads all the data file locations as one. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Whats priam? Are we talking about Cassandra, or NetFlix or the King of Troy or something else?

Comment: Are you referring to this: https://github.com/Netflix/Priam
?

Comment: The Netflix Priam. I updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try a comma separated list:

```
priam.data.location=/priam/first/data,/priam/second/data,/priam/third/data
```